# Linq query to exclude from a List when a property value of List of different type are equal?

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a List of type Fee from which I need to exclude the ones that have an ID that exists in another List of type int.

```
List<int> ExcludedFeeIDs = new List<int>{1,2,3,4};

List<Fee> MyFees = (from c in ctx.Fees
                    select c).ToList();
```

Example: 
List GoodFees = (from f in ctx.Fees where f.FeeID!=**One of the IDs in ExcludedFeeIDs**);

Help please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
var MyFees = from c in ctx.Fees
             where !ExcludedFeeIDs.Contains(c.FeeID)
             select c;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Yannick.

Comment: For simply queries some people prefer using the dot notation: 

var myFees = ctx.Fees.Where(fee => !ExcludedFeeIDs.Contains(fee.FeeID));